# PHP - Edit elements is gone after updating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Goodmorning. My problem is after clicking the update button the edit elements are gone like the title, date, content and the image only the echo output is shown "successfully updated". What i want to do is after clicking the update button the elements will stay there and it will echo there.

Here is my edit2.php 
[image]

after i click the update button only the output "Successfully update" is shown the edit elements is gone
[image]

here is the php code for edit2.php

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');

 $newsid = $_GET['news_id'];

    if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            /* bind parameters */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newsid);

            /* execute query */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            /* get the result set */
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            /* fetch row from the result set */
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }

    }


    if(isset($_POST['update'])){


        if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {
          $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
          $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
          $newsimage="img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

          $title = $_POST['titles'];
          $date = $_POST['dates'];
          $content = $_POST['contents'];

          $sql ="UPDATE news SET news_title ='$title', news_date ='$date', news_content = '$content', news_image ='$newsimage' WHERE news_id = '$newsid'";
          mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          echo "successfully updated";
        }

        else{
          $title = $_POST['titles'];
          $date = $_POST['dates'];
          $content = $_POST['contents'];
          $sql ="UPDATE news SET news_title ='$title', news_date ='$date', news_content = '$content' WHERE news_id = '$newsid'";
          mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          echo "successfully updated";
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
        ?>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="edit2.php?news_id=<?php echo $row['news_id']; ?>" >
            Title<input type ="text" name ="titles" value="<?php echo $row['news_title']; ?>"/><br>
            Date<input type ="text" name="dates" value="<?php echo $row['news_date']; ?>" /><br>
            Content<textarea name="contents"><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></textarea>
            <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
            <img id="blah" src="<?php echo $row['news_image']; ?>" alt="your image" style="width:200px; height:140px;"/>

            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
        </form>

        <?php
    }

?>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#image").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of this `if` block,

```
if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){ ...
```

When you submit the form, `$_POST['esubmit']` will be not get set and hence, the form won't get displayed again. So your `if` block should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['esubmit']) || isset($_POST['update'])){ ...
```

Overall, you need to change your first and third `if` blocks in the following way,

```
if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        /* bind parameters */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newsid);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* get the result set */
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        /* fetch row from the result set */
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        /* get all values */
        $title = $row['news_title'];
        $date = $row['news_date'];;
        $content = $row['news_content'];
        $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
    }

}
```

And

```
if(isset($_POST['esubmit']) || isset($_POST['update'])){
    ?>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action ="edit2.php?news_id=<?php echo $newsid; ?>" >
            Title<input type ="text" name ="titles" value="<?php if(isset($title)){ echo $title; } ?>"/><br>
            Date<input type ="text" name="dates" value="<?php if(isset($date)){ echo $date; } ?>" /><br>
            Content<textarea name="contents"><?php if(isset($content)){ echo $content; } ?></textarea>
            <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
            <img id="blah" src="<?php if(isset($newsimage)){ echo $newsimage; } ?>" alt="your image" style="width:200px; height:140px;"/>

            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
        </form>

    <?php
}
```

---

**From the extended discussion,**

Since you're making image upload optional, you need to fetch image details in the `else` block where you process the form in case user doesn't upload an image, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {

        // your code

    }else{
        // your code

        /* get the image details*/
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT news_image FROM news WHERE news_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newsid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $newsimage = $row['news_image'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @nethken May be `$newsimage` is not set, or may be the image path is wrong. Do `var_dump($newsimage);` and see what you're getting.

Comment: @nethken Performing the database operation again in the update block is an overkill. First do [this thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155482/php-edit-elements-is-gone-after-updating/38155539?noredirect=1#comment63740621_38155539) to debug the issue.

Comment: Undefined variable: newsimage in C:\xampp\htdocs\studentportal\edit2.php on line 58
NULL here is the error sir.

Comment: @nethken That's very obvious because `$newsimage` is not available immediately after this line, `if(isset($_POST['update'])){`. Do `var_dump($newsimage);` after this line, `<img id="blah" src="<?php if(isset($newsimage)){ echo $newsimage; } ?>" ...` and see what you're getting.

Comment: image cant put there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116241/discussion-between-rajdeep-paul-and-nethken).

Comment: same error C:\xampp\htdocs\studentportal\edit2.php on line 58 NULL here is the error